# Is there a app or software that will allow me to access a Zip file that was down loaded from the Hightail web site?

Tags: java, libreoffice

I am using a Asus  laptop, running on Ubuntu 15.10, -  (64bit) - however, my problem is this, I downloaded two zip files from the Hightail website, and I am unable to read the files. when I click on the downloaded files, with the Libreoffice writer, all I get is a page full of code. It appears to me, that a lot of the files were put together with a Java Script setup.

The information is suppose to be dealing with law, not a page full of code. 
Frankly, I am new to Ubuntu, and clueless on what to do. i really would like some help with this, on how to access this Zip file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

ZIP files are archives, not text files. They contain other files that are compressed so as to save space. A ZIP file can be thought of as a compressed folder. I'm going to bet that what's *inside* the ZIP is what you want to open with LibreOffice.

To open the ZIP, simply browse to it in a file manager and double-click it. In the window that pops up, click the <kbd>Extract...</kbd> button to extract whatever's inside. Click <kbd>Show Files</kbd> when prompted and a folder will open with the files that were inside the ZIP.

You should find a file there you can open.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the `unzip` command to "unzip" or extract a zip file in the terminal to make it readable.

For example, if I have a file named `Hightail.zip` located in my Downloads directory, I would run the following command to unzip or extract the file or files:

```
unzip ~/Downloads/"Hightail.zip" -d ~/Downloads/
```

---

To explain:

The first part of the command: `unzip ~/Downloads/"Hightail.zip"` tells the computer to unzip the file that is specified.

The last part of the command  `-d ~/Downloads/` tells the computer *where* to put the newly extracted file or files. In this example, the new files would be found in the Downloads directory when finished.